# Capitalization independent react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to give user an interface where the props are independent of capitalization. For example:

```js
<MyComponent prop1="value1" Prop2="value2" />
<MyComponent ProP1="value1" prop2="value2" />
```

both should be valid and work the same way. While I want to avoid modifying the original props, as the props may contain a large set of data, I am planning to avoid cloning them as well. Is there a good way I can achieve this?

Comment: It does not sound like a good idea to let users implement an interface without strict naming for props and variables

Comment: It's a kind of interesting question, maybe you could distinguish the real cases with more specific conditions, like `only ignore first letter` or `ignore all uppercase`, there should be programming solutions for each of them I guess.

Comment: Yes, may be I asked a little too generalized question. So its more like, useHCEffect and useHcEffect, I want both of these to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing that, but that wasn't your question. Your question was whether you *can*. :-D Yes, you can, via destructuring with default values. For instance:

```
const MyComponent = ({Prop1, prop1 = Prop1, Prop2, prop2 = Prop2}) => {
    // Use `prop1` and `prop2` here
};
```

or as a function declaration:

```
function MyComponent({Prop1, prop1 = Prop1, Prop2, prop2 = Prop2}) {
    // Use `prop1` and `prop2` here
}
```

or in the `render` of a class component:

```
render() {
    const {Prop1, prop1 = Prop1, Prop2, prop2 = Prop2} = this.props;
    // Use `prop1` and `prop2` here
}
```

The parameter destructuring `{Prop1, prop1 = Prop1, Prop2, prop2 = Prop2}` says:

- Extract `Prop1` (will be `undefined` if not provided)
- Extract `prop1` (will be `undefined` if not provided) and default it to the value of `Prop1` if it's not provided/is `undefined`
- (Same for `Prop2`/`prop2`)

Here's an example (just using a plain function, since this is about destructuring):

```js
function example({Prop1, prop1 = Prop1, Prop2, prop2 = Prop2}) {
    console.log(`prop1 = "${prop1}"`);
    console.log(`prop2 = "${prop2}"`);
}

example({Prop1: "a1", prop2: "b1"});
example({prop1: "a2", Prop2: "b2"});
```

---

*(I've been known to use this to work around the `class` vs. `className` silliness: `{"class": cls, className = cls}` then use `className` in the code.)*

---

Alternatively, since props is an object, you could convert all the prop names to lower case:

```
const {prop1, prop2} = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(props).map(([name, value]) => [name.toLowerCase(), value])
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I asked a pretty generalized question, my use case is a little specific. Its more like I want useHCEffect and useHcEffect both to be valid. I get the idea now. Thanks again!

Comment: @gt18 - I literally **just** realized that you may have meant any capitalization, and came back to add something to the answer -- added now. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const inpProps = {};
Object.keys(props).forEach((key) => {
    inpProps[key.toLowerCase()]= props[key];
});
```